# In a Boeing 767, what percentage of the aluminum is in structural components?

Tags: aircraft-design, boeing-767

For a Boeing 767 (model year 2000), does anyone know how much aluminum is in 'structural' components, as a percentage of the total amount? And specifically the wings?

Comment: I'm guessing that you're asking, "Out of all of the structural material in the aircraft, what percentage of it is aluminum?" Is that correct?

Comment: Total structure, [at first sight 80%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpZQX.png). ([source](https://books.google.fr/books?id=cuIh1Qb7xc8C&pg=PA143&lpg=PA143&#v=onepage&q&f=false))

Comment: For the structural wing box, upper plank, lower plank, front and rear spar webs, and ribs, it's going to be pretty much all aluminum except some of the fasteners (Hi Lite or Hi Shear steel pin rivets in some areas).  I would think over 90% aluminum alloy of some kind.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I edited your question to hopefully make it a little clearer. If I made a mistake, you can edit again yourself or roll back the change. If you're new to StackExchange, the [tour] may be helpful to see how the site works.